# Custom column parse query

Tags: android, parse-platform

I am using Parse as back-end for my Android Application.I have created two custom columns in the User Class.Now I want my application user to signup with my application.I am unable to store user data for the custom columns.How do i do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Directly from the Parse Docs:

```
ParseUser user = new ParseUser();
user.setUsername("my name");
user.setPassword("my pass");
user.setEmail("email@example.com");

// other fields can be set just like with ParseObject
user.put("phone", "650-253-0000");

user.signUpInBackground(new SignUpCallback() {
  public void done(ParseException e) {
    if (e == null) {
      // Hooray! Let them use the app now.
    } else {
      // Sign up didn't succeed. Look at the ParseException
      // to figure out what went wrong
    }
  }
});
```

I suggest you read the Parse docs very thoroughly - most anything you will want to do with the service will be somewhere in the docs, they are very good.

Comment: I read the documents and found this solution...but this doesn't seem to work for me.The registration fails when i use this.

Comment: @gambit - you need to post your code so I can take a look and better help you