# Accessing a custom column in Parse.com user table returning me null

Tags: android, parse-platform

I am trying to retrieve a new column called "address" I created in Parse User in my android app. But it returns me nullPointerException error and returns me nothing although I filled the address in the table. 
This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25474073/custom-column-parse-query) only shows the way to store your custom field in the user table but I need to retrieve what I stored there. 
This is my code:

```
ParseUser pUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
userAddress.setText(pUser.getString("address").toString());
```

I tried `get("address")` as well but still it returns me nothing. Is there something I'm missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright, I found the answer on my own. It turns out that Parse caches the `ParseUser.getCurrentUser()` object locally and the reason I wasn't able to get the data from server was because I changed the data on server and the client cache wasn't updated.
I was able to fix this by fetching the ParseUser object from the server:

```
ParseUser.getCurrentUser().fetchInBackground();
```

and then after the object is retrieved from the server I was able to get the address field on my client.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call it using a Query, then display it in a textView/editText. Try the following:

```
final ParseQuery<ParseObject> address = ParseQuery.getQuery("//Class Name");
    address.getFirstInBackground(new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {

        public void done(ParseObject reqAdd, ParseException e) {

            if (address != null) {
                Log.d("quizOne", "Got it");
                //Retrieve Age
                String //CreateNewString = reqAdd.getString("//Column name");
                TextView //textView Name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.//textView ID);
                //textViewName.setText(//StringName);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Successfully Recieved Address",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


            } else {
                Log.d("//EnterName", "//Enter Error Message");
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Can't receive address", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Can't I just use the normal ParseUser object methods? This code I guess should work. Ill try that and Ill let you know.

Comment: You could do. This method adds it into a textView/editText which I find easier to display on my application.

Answer (score -1):

Short answer: that user probably just doesn't have an address set.

Long answer: your code snippet will throw exceptions often, and you should expect and handle those, or use tests to avoid throwing them.

Read this page: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Programming/Preventing_NullPointerException

Key example/excerpt:

```
Object obj = null;
obj.toString();  // This statement will throw a NullPointerExcept
```

So pUser.getString("address") appears correct. But calling .toString() on the result requires you to be try/catching the exception. Maybe do

```
ParseUser pUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
if (pUser.getString("address") != null) {
    userAddress.setText(pUser.getString("address"));
}
```

BTW, I believe the error is "nullPointerException" fyi! :)

Comment: Yea. My bad.. its nullPointerException. I edited that. Its not about the nullPointerException error. It returns nothing from my User table. And My user table has an address field and all the records have data. Its I think something about parse or maybe the way I am trying to do this is not correct.

Comment: The question is not about NPE, it's about why the author can't retrieve a custom field value from the User