# A field of _User in Parse is always null

Tags: android, parse-platform

I'm using Parse 1.9.4 for developing a backend for my mobile app.
I'm faced with a problem. 
On the cloud I set a phone number for a user. 
I can check that the number was set in the Parse web-console by opening the `_User` table, where I see the actual value. 
But I can't retrieve it on the client side.

My latest try was the following:

```
ParseUser.getCurrentUser().fetchInBackground(new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {
    @Override
    public void done(ParseObject parseObject, ParseException e) {
        System.out.println(parseObject.getObjectId());
        System.out.println(parseObject.get("username"));
        System.out.println(parseObject.get("phone"));
    }
});
```

Here's the output of the code above:

```
07-27 09:46:39.113  17452-17452/com.example.app I/System.out﹕ NpD5l9Gw54
07-27 09:46:39.113  17452-17452/com.example.app I/System.out﹕ HOMAiJeuil7qD2kK1cUjZLVkj
07-27 09:46:39.113  17452-17452/com.example.app I/System.out﹕ null
```

I can get the `username` as well as `objectId`, but no `phone`, which is always `null`. I set every checkbox in the permissions for `_User`, so the permissions must not be the case. What may be the cause of this behavior?

**update.** Here's a screenshot of the data browser:
[image]

**Update.** Here's a similar question without a satisfying answer: [Accessing a custom column in Parse.com user table returning me null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28791134/accessing-a-custom-column-in-parse-com-user-table-returning-me-null)

The output from the Parse console.

```
I2015-07-26T11:46:11.550Z]v19 Ran cloud function sendVerificationCode for user NpD5l9Gw54 with:
  Input: {"phone":"11223"}
  Result: {
"cost": "0.7",
"cnt": 1
}
```

Following the @danh suggestions, I checked that if I modify a user on the client, I can get the data back on the client, but it doesn't get to the cloud (so in the data browser I see the old value).

```
    ParseUser.getCurrentUser().put("phone", "12345");
    System.out.println(ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getString("phone"));
```

The output:

```
07-27 10:52:36.995  14621-14621/com.example.app I/System.out﹕ 12345
```

Comment: Please snap an image of the row in the data browser and post it here along with the log output.

Comment: @danh I posted an image and now I got an idea. May it be because I try to get a property of an anonymous user? I don't know what else to think.

Comment: @danh I posted the output. If you meant the output from the Parse console, there are no errors there. There's just info about what function got executed.

Comment: That's the output I meant.  Without it, you leave yourself open to the same unsatisfying answers in the other question.  With it, you leave me stumped.  Can you put something in that column then immediately get it back?

Comment: @danh I posted the output from the console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this, will it produce the result and let me know your result

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("_User");
query.whereEqualTo("objectId", "NpD5l9Gw54");
query.getFirstInBackground(new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {
      public void done(ParseObject object, ParseException e) {
         if (object == null) {
           Log.d("score", "The getFirst request failed.");
         } else {
            System.out.println(object.get("username"));
            System.out.println(object.get("phone"));
         }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It worked. But why using the `ParseUser.getCurrentUser()` doesn't work? If I'll be using the queries, it'll be bad for the design of my application (I've already set methods relying on `ParseUser.getCurrentUser`)

Comment: Please try with the login function.

Comment: ParseUser.logInInBackground("username", null, new     LogInCallback() {
  public void done(ParseUser user, ParseException e) {
    if (user != null) {
      // Hooray! The user is logged in.
    } else {
      // Signup failed. Look at the ParseException to see what happened.
    }
  }
});

Comment: But according to the docs: "The ParseUser obtained from getCurrentUser() will always be authenticated". So it must be the same whether I obtain a user through the `ParseUser.logInInBackground()`  or `ParseUser.getCurrentUser()`. And I can't use the `ParseUser.logInInBackground()` because my user is an anonymous user (an anonymous user in my app becomes a normal user after phone verification).

Comment: ParseUser.getCurrentUser().put("phone", "12345");

Comment: ParseUser.getCurrentUser().saveInBackground();